# Graphical Representation of Git Hub?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using source tree and was wondering if there is anyway for me to see a graphical representation of git hub to see that I have no totally screwed up my repository.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "a graphical representation of GitHub"? What do you expect?

Comment: Are you looking for the [network graph](https://github.com/github/hub/network)?

Comment: Here's a [graphical representation of Github](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png).

Comment: Are you talking about branches and merges which can be represented graphically? You should say if you are.

Comment: yeah I was hopping for like a network graph kind of thing. Sadly am using source tree and that is not graphical enough for me. I am new at this lol.

Comment: @Sven Lol good one. Cute.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Clarify your question with examples of the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, he wants to see repository graph at the left-hand side of SourceTree app. You can get it on your terminal window/shell/command-line with

`git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

as @[name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5553471/name) said.

Or, you can use some tools like [GitUp](http://gitup.co/) if SourceTree is not enough.

*Requires Mac OS X 10.8 or later—OS X Yosemite recommended.*

Comment: If only there was a windows version :( of GitUp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a representation of a single github repository, just clone it locally and inspect it with SourceTree.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

That should help you to see the network graph in the command line.